# angular 7 retain 'objects id based' from URL after redirect

Tags: angular, angular-router, cesiumjs

As a continues for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639474/angular-2-retain-state-from-url-after-redirect) 
as recommend for the up answer,
I build a service that saves all the needed parameters to come back to the same state as before navigating form a specific URL.
How can I return to the same state, when I have an object that builds by div id like cesium / open layer/ leaflet etc. without creating a new one?
for example :
`<div id="main-cesium" ></div>`
I save his viewer in the service by giving him the div id and some initial options and when I navigate from this page I can't go back to this specific object.
what can I do?

very shortly example code:

```
//app-routing.module  
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {path: 'main', component: MainPageComponent,  pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'item', component: Items,  pathMatch: 'full'},
 ];
//MainPage TPL  
<div id="main-cesium"></div> 

//MainPageComponent   
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.mainViewer = this.mainService.getMainCesium("main-cesium") 
    //check if already exist if yes return this object else build one
}

//MainService     
getMainCesiumViewer(mainCesiumId: string) {
    if(!this.mainCesiumViewer){
        this.mainCesiumViewer = new Cesium.Viewer(mainCesiumId,someConfigObj);
    }
    return this.mainCesiumViewer;
 }


//navigate to item  
this.router.navigate([ '/item']);

//mavigate to main  
this.router.navigate([ '/main']);
```

Comment: Please provide some code to help explain your question

Comment: I tried to send just the relevant code if this still missing I will provide more @TomMettam